# After adding StreamReader code, can't add variables to my text file StreamWriter

Tags: c#, object, reference, instance

I have a problem.

This is the code:

```
StreamReader lasa = new StreamReader("klubbar.txt");
while (true)
{
    string line = lasa.ReadLine();

    if (line == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    antal++;
    Console.WriteLine(line);

}
lasa.Close();
```

These line of code has caused me a problem with writing my variable to my text file:

```
StreamWriter sparaklubb = new StreamWriter("klubbar.txt");

for (int i = 1; i <= antal; i++)
{
    sparaklubb.Write(klubbar[i].id + "\t");
    sparaklubb.Write(klubbar[i].klubbnamn + "\t");
    sparaklubb.Write(klubbar[i].vip + "\t");
    sparaklubb.Write(klubbar[i].dansgolv + "\t");
    sparaklubb.Write(klubbar[i].intrade + "\t");
    sparaklubb.Write(klubbar[i].casino + "\t");
    sparaklubb.WriteLine(klubbar[i].genre);
}
sparaklubb.Close();
```

Because I get this error:

[image]

I don't have a clue how to fix it, if I remove the StreamReader code everything works.

Comment: Please post the full error details as text (not as a picture. That doesn't google well).

Comment: Have you checked if `klubbar` contains a valid object-reference?

Comment: Where are you putting the lines into klubbar[]? And why is your indexing of klubbar[] starting at 1 rather then 0?

Comment: Would be nice to know the line the exception occurs on.

Comment: `int i = 1; i <= antal; i++` is suspect but we don't know about `klubbar` and `antal`

Comment: Is the reader code before the writer code?  How is `antal` being set when you remove the writer code?  Do you have `null`s in your `klubbar` array?

Comment: It's maybe better to give you guys the whole project?
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13409794/ConsoleApplication8.rar

It is the "LagTillKlubb.cs"

Comment: No, that's not the way. It's up to the asker to ask a decent question. Put some effort in selecting and formatting your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not resetting `antal` to 0 after the reader code.  This is causing your code that is inserting into the `klubbar` array to start at whatever the current value of `antal` is, for example maybe the reader read in 5 lines so `antal` is 5.  That means you didn't put an object into the `klubbar` array at positions 1-4 (you really should start an index at 0).  Then in your writer code you are trying to reference members on a `null` value at `klubbar[1]`.  Removing the reader code "fixes" the problem because `antal` will be 0 when you start putting objects into the `klubbar` array.  My suggestion is to use a `List<klubb>` instead of an array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but how can I do so i can start to fill out index 0 in my array? I just started with my c# course in Sweden for three days ago so I am not so high at this but i do my very best! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

based on a quick look at your code you never populate your array, as such each entity in your array is null, so when you attempt to access a field on your object, the object itself is null.

Hence the object not set exception.

You need to correctly implement the population from the text file in your streamreader section

```
        klubb[] klubbar = new klubb[100]; //Skapa en vektor där varje element kan behålla flera olika variblar från klassen "klubb"

        //IF YOU REMOVE THIS STREAMREADERCODE WITH THE WHILE LOOP EVERYTHING WILL WORK FINE
        StreamReader lasa = new StreamReader("klubbar.txt");
        while (true)
        {
            string line = lasa.ReadLine();

            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            antal++;
            Console.WriteLine(line);
           // klubbar[antal] = line;     //ADD EACH LINE IN TEXTFILE TO AN SEPAREATE INDEX IN ARRAY klubar
        }
        lasa.Close();
```

As you read in each line you need to parse that line into your Klubb object. which should be simple enough as it looks like your file is tab delimited.

```
1       Harrys  True    6   100 blackjack   klubbfan
2        xoY    True    6   100 blackajacka klubb
3       lounge  True    6   100 blackjacka  klubb
```

in response to comment, so you could do something like:

```
klubbar[antal] = GetKlubbFromString(line); 
^ this line is to replace the line in your stream reader section

private static klubb GetKlubbFromString(string line)
    {
        string[] lineItems = line.Split('\t');

        //1       Harrys  True    6   100 blackjack   klubbfan


        return new klubb
                   {
                       id = Convert.ToInt32(lineItems[0]),
                       klubbnamn = lineItems[1],
                       vip = Convert.ToBoolean(lineItems[2]),
                       dansgolv = Convert.ToInt32(lineItems[3]),
                       intrade = Convert.ToInt32(lineItems[4]),
                       casino = lineItems[5],
                       genre = lineItems[6]
                   };
    }
```

i personally wouldn't use Convert.To due to exceptions, i favor TryParse, and i'm sure some brighter SO members will come along and offer better ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you structured and easy to understand answer. I just wounder how to put each line in my text file into a element with the index based on the variable "antal".

Comment: You could split the line variable via line.split() passing '\t' into the split method, which will give you back a string array string[] of line parts. which you can then parse to the correct type. e.g. int.TryParse(line[0], out Klubb[i].Id)  for the string items you won't need to parse and can just set the objects field directly

Comment: I've added an example of what i mean in my answer above